# Applescript for specific System Preferences pane

Tags: applescript, system-settings

I'm trying to write an applescript to get me to a specific section of the system preferences - Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services and hopefully to a specific service as well. I've gotten a part of the way with this:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
```

This gets me to the Shortcuts portion of the Keyboard prefs pane but I'd like to drill down further into the correct selection. Is there a way to select a specific service in this prefs pane? Ultimately I'm wanting to direct the end user to change a keyboard shortcut for a service previously installed.

Comment: My script wasn't working, fixed it, although it's a bit uglier. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a script I just wrote that'll do it. This will get you to the shortcuts tab of the Keyboard preference pane, and select a row from the left and right columns:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until (window 1 exists)
        end repeat
        tell window 1
            #modify these to specify a row in the left column, or the right column, respectively
            
            repeat until (row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
            end repeat

            select row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1
            
            repeat until (row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
            end repeat

            select row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Here's the version you can use which identifies the rows by name. Sort of hacky, but it should work well.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until (window 1 exists)
        end repeat
        tell window 1
            #modify these to specify a row in the left column, or the right column, respectively
        
            repeat until (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
            end repeat
        
            select (first row of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 whose value of static text 1 is equal to "Services")
        
            repeat until (rows of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
            end repeat
        
            select (first row of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 whose name of UI element 2 is equal to "Open URL")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thanks! This did exactly what I wanted. I've been messing around with UI scripting unsuccessfully for awhile. It's nice to get a good example of this.

Comment: Is there way to select a row from it's name and not it's number? I want this to work on machines I've never used (a part of an installer). I can't get it to work but I've tried `select row "Open URL"…` IT doesn't seem to want to take the name. Any tips?

Comment: I have made the requested changes. It's sort of hacky, as GUI scripting tends to be, but it gets the job done. I can't verify if this will work across operating systems without modification, however (I'm running 10.11). This certainly can be done on every version of OS X I'm familiar with (back to 10.5), but the syntax may be slightly different, and you'd have to check for that. With any luck, this may "just work".